# How do I prevent requirejs from including all the source files and only include the module files?

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

When I build a project with r.js (I'm doing it via grunt, but I digress), it uglifies and compacts all of the javascript files of the project and includes them in the build folder, even though all those files have been compacted into a single javascript file and are no longer used in their individual forms.

I'm using modules, so I can't use the "out" flag b/c it's not compatible. I'm using grunt-contrib-clean to clean up all the extra files, but if I could just avoid including them in the first place, that would be ideal.

Here is my grunt options.js:

```
module.exports = {
  appDir: 'src',
  baseUrl: 'js/',
  mainConfigFile: 'src/js/common.js',
  dir: 'www',
  modules: [
    {
      name: 'common',
      include: [
          'jquery',
          'underscore',
          'handlebars',
          'hbs',
          'i18nprecompile',
          'json2',
          'Class'
      ]
    },
    {
        name: 'app/page1',
        exclude: ['common']
    },
    {
        name: 'app/page2',
        exclude: ['common']
    }
  ]
};
```

When it builds, it includes all the files in the lib folder (when the only one needed is require.js), and it includes uglified versions all the javascript files imported by page1 and page2, even though all those files have been combined into page1.js and page2.js.

Am I missing something or is post build cleanup simply a fact of life?

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply fixed by setting `removeCombined` to false:

```
    //If set to true, any files that were combined into a build layer will be
    //removed from the output folder.
    removeCombined: false,
```

In depth details on any of the other build options [can be found in this example file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js).

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you can use:

```
skipDirOptimize: true, 
removeCombined: true
```

`skipDirOptimize: true` will prevent requirejs to optimize other files

`removeCombined: true` will remove all combined to module files